# Is Foundation (by Zurb) an MVC framework?

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, zurb-foundation, canjs

I'm confused that Foundation is not listed on http://todomvc.com .

Is there difference between AngularJS, Backbone, CanJS.... and Foundation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foundation is DESIGN ONLY (with some ajvascript to make it act/look nice). It's bascially a big CSS framework comparable to Bootstrap.

You won't be able to build an application with Foundation... But you can use it WITH Backbone, Angular, etc.